# Почему не отрабатывает одна и та же функция еще раз?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем мой косяк. [Вот тестовая страница](http://verstka.test30.ru/test/). Там есть выбор автомобиля. После выбора марки показывается выбор модели. По идее после выбора модели должен показываться выбор года, но почему-то год остается disabled. Почему такое происходит?

Вот код:

```
function selectAuto(classSelect, pathJson, firstOption) {
    $('select.' + classSelect).find('option').remove();
    $('select.' + classSelect).append( "<option>" + firstOption + "</option>" );
    $.getJSON(pathJson, function (data) {
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    $('select.' + classSelect).append( "<option>" + val + "</option>" );
  });
});
    setTimeout(function() {
  $('.tire-selection-select.' + classSelect).attr('disabled', false).trigger('refresh');
}, 100)
};

$('.jq-selectbox.select-mark .jq-selectbox__dropdown li:not(:first-child)').on('click', function(){
    selectAuto('select-model', 'js/json/models.json', 'Модель');
});

$('.jqselect.select-model li:not(:first-child)').on('click', function(){
    selectAuto('select-year', 'js/json/year.json', 'Год');
});
```

Comment: Год не disabled, а не заполнен данными.

Comment: Он disabled. Функция просто не отрабатывает, чтобы disabled ушел + не работает подгрузка из JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в `$(document).ready` навешиваете клик-обработчик на элементы в выборке `$('.jqselect.select-model li:not(:first-child)')`. Однако, пока не выбрана марка, никаких элементов в моделях нет. То есть Ваш обработчик оказывается ни к чему не прикреплен. Более того, каждый раз когда выбирается марка, все опции моделей удаляются и создаются заново. Используйте делегирование:

```
$(document).on('click', '.jqselect.select-model li:not(:first-child)', function(){
  selectAuto('select-year', 'js/json/year.json', 'Год');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!